# Disable firefox from loading content from the internet

Tags: firefox, proxy

I am looking to view the source from some html files in Firefox, that i have already downloaded. I do not want the browser to download any files when opening the html (e.g. images etc). What is the easiest way of preventing firefox from begin able to access the internet?

I suspect it is by setting the proxy values, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to avoid this is to disable your network adapter. I have tried this before by changing proxy settings and have found in some instances that if the proxy server couldnt be found that firefix will try connecting directly.